# Abstracting and connecting 2 external libraries

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, embedded, abstraction

I'm writing the UI layer for my embedded C++ project. For graphic manipulation, I wanted to use the Adafruit_GFX library. I've created an interface

```
class IRenderer {
public:
    virtual void drawPixel(int16_t x, int16_t y, uint16_t color) = 0;
    virtual void drawCircle(
            int16_t x0,
            int16_t y0,
            int16_t r,
            uint16_t color
        ) = 0;
    };
    ...
```

and connect my interface via bridge with actual library:

```
class AdafruitRendererBridge : public IRenderer {
private:
    Adafruit_GFX &gfx;

public:
    virtual void drawPixel(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t color) {
        gfx.drawPixel(x, y, color);
    }

    ...

    AdafruitRendererBridge(Adafruit_GFX &_gfx) : gfx(_gfx) {}
};
```

That way, I'm making my code independent of the external library API. Also, I'm making my code testable, as now I can create mock implementing this interface and run unit tests on my host machine without the actual hardware environment that this library needs. Now I'd like to use another external library, ArduinoMenu, that would create a UI for me using provided renderer. The problem is that this library needs a concrete object of the Arduino_GFX type. I've abstracted it and just used my interface. What would be the solution here to initialize ArduinoMenu while using my interface?

I think using template here is an option; however, I'd like to get an explicitly defined set of methods that need to be present, like interfaces do.

Other option is to create some kind of revered bridge:

```
class RendererAdafruitBridge : public Adafruit_GFX {
private:
    IRenderer &renderer;

public:
    virtual void drawPixel(int16_t x, int16_t y, uint16_t color) override {
        renderer.drawPixel(x, y, color);
    }
   
    ...

    RendererAdafruitBridge(IRenderer &_renderer) : renderer(_renderer) {}
};
```

However, not every method in Adafruit_GFX that I would need is marked as virtual. Also, there are a lot of methods in Adafruit_GFX and I would need to list them all twice. First in IRenderer and now in this reversed bridge kind of thing.

Comment: _The problem is that this library [ArduinoMenu] needs a concrete object of the Arduino_GFX type_ Why?  I thought it was more generic than that.

Comment: Side note: once a member function is made `virtual` it stays `virtual`. `drawPixel` and `drawCircle` is `virtual` for all children of `IRenderer` without need for the `virtual` qualifier. But watch out for [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)

Comment: Side note: it's hard to assign an object with a reference member because a reference cannot be reassigned to a different object. If this becomes an issue, you may need a pointer in place of a reference at `IRenderer &renderer;`

Comment: Addressing the problem, look at how the non-virtual functions are implemented in `Adafruit_GFX`. You may find the other functions you think you need to override are actually well-implemented using the functions you had to override.